# More efficient way of comparing two numbers

Tags: javascript, performance, comparison

I was challenged to see if two numbers are equal in javascript without using the '=' operator so i came up with this:

```
function isEqual(a, b) {
    try {
        [{ foo: true }][a - b].foo
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

But i think there must be a more efficient way of doing it so i'm looking for options.

Comment: How about `return !(a - b);`

Comment: Without using the `=` operator would be `a == b` or `a === b`. If you mean, without the `==` or `===` operator, `Object.is(a, b)` (works for `NaN`, too, but considers `-0` and `0` different), or what Pointy said. But `a - b` won’t work for infinities.

Comment: Not sure why you need that `foo` property and the exception handling: `Boolean([true][a - b])` (ofc Pointy's approach is even simpler)

Comment: Thanks for your sugestions guys , didn't thought you could do it this easy

Comment: what about `return !(a>b) && !(a<b)`?

Comment: @Edwin Good idea. OP didn't say anything about how `NaN` needs to be handled, so I guess we can ignore that

Comment: Please don't delete [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167666/what-other-weird-ways-of-doing-arythmetics-in-javascript-or-other-languages-do) and then ask the same question again.

Comment: I made a whole differente question, if you noticed i was looking for alternatives there.

Comment: I can't see the difference between "_What other ... ways_" and "_options_". It's good to know, that deleting too many questions leads to the question ban.

Comment: read the question title, if you can't see a difference there must be something wrong with you... More effienct way =/= Please show me different arythmetic tactis.... the question is clearly different

Comment: They are essentially asking the same. Anyway, I'm not going to argue about this, it's your account and you do what ever you wish with it as long as you can ...

Comment: Would you feel more comfortable if i delete the question? that's fine by me

Comment: Oh, no, please don't, that would be one more event leading to the question ban.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the fastest way is by using bitwise operators. This method is ~35% faster in JavaScript than using `==`.

`!(a^b)` or `(a^b) == 0`

Example:

```
!(1^1) // true
!(2^1) // false
```

Note: This doesn’t work for floating-point numbers and for values outside the range of 32-bit ints. ( thanks to Xufox for pointing this out )

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: This doesn’t work for floating-point numbers and for values outside the range of 32-bit ints.

Comment: That is true @Xufox poster didn't specify limitations/requirements here.